# Baum Welch and a 1 state Markov model?

Tags: hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization

I'm using the Baum-Welch algorithm to determine the parameters of a 2 state Hidden Markov Model. It determines fairly well. When I increase the sample size, the estimations get more concentrated, and closer to the true value, which is 3. In the picture below, we can see that. We start at sample size 50, and then with a step of 50, we reach 500.

[image]

However, when I apply the Baum-Welch to a 1 state Markov Model (it could be easier to compute just the usual ML estimators in this case though), something strange happens. It seems to converge in prob to the true value, in this case -3, but the precision/concentration of the values around the true value is much lower.
Should I be worried about this? I think that the Baum-Welch can be applied to a 1-state.

[image]

Edit: I'm adding two graphics with the estimations of the std deviation of the model in both cases. The true value is 1.

Below: with different parameters(2 states)
[image: With different parameters(2 state)]

Below: with only 1 state

[image]

Comment: You need to explain what parameter is being plotted here.  Also, why do you know the true value?  Is the data being generated from the model?  Are there any other parameters besides the one being plotted?

Comment: Yes, I'm generating the data from a known model. The parameter influences the mean of the distribution from which the data is generated.

Comment: That still isn't enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @TomMinka The other parameters being estimated are the variance, but it's not dependent on the state. Only the mean is dependent on the state. The mean follows an AR(1) process, where we estimate 2 parameters, one dependent on the state.

Comment: Try plotting the estimate of variance in the two cases.

Comment: @TomMinka The true values of the variance are the same in both cases. What type of conclusions could I take from the estimations of the variance?

Comment: The estimated variance controls the concentration of the mean around the true value.

Comment: @TomMinka Sorry for the delay. I've updated the question with the graphics you asked.